# img tag only appears when there is another img tag next to it

Tags: html, image

Hello I have here a html. img tag only appear whenever there's another tag next to it. here's are the directories. the image does not appear when i remove the other img tag
image 
 - e:/html/lmcl.png 
html
 - e:/html/firstproject.html 


    
        First website

```
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="main-nav>

            <img src="lmcl.png" alt="Wake Forest Baptist Health Lexington Medical Center">
            <img src="lmcl.png" alt="Wake Forest Baptist Health Lexington Medical Center">

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Close the main-nav with the missing double quote, image tags and try?

Comment: Mark the answer of Mario

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing quote.

```
<div id="main-nav">
```